# How to fix this grammar so that it could evaluate postfix correctly

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, operators, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I'm writing a grammar that should convert infix to postfix. Our teacher told us to change this grammar:

```
E -> TT'  
T -> FF'  
T'-> +T | -T | nil  
F -> (E) | id | num
F' -> *F | /F | nil
```

Note: tokens are `+,-,*,/, ^` (pow). The problem is power operator . I don't know how to change the grammar so that it could parse power too.

Thanks in advance.